# inserting the same tuple in a relation more than once

Tags: sql

as a relation is a set of tuples and (due to Inherent model-based constrain)
the relation can't contain the same tuple twice
but if the table has no primary key it will accept to insert the same row twice with no constrains
can anyone explain what is the difference here.

### solved

> "Table" is another term for "relation"; although there is the difference in that a table is usually a multiset (bag) of rows where a relation is a set and does not allow duplicates.

from

[wiki table explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(database)#:%7E:text=%22Table%22%20is%20another%20term%20for,and%20does%20not%20allow%20duplicates.&text=Views%20also%20function%20as%20relational,are%20calculated%20at%20query%20time.)

Comment: SQL table don't follow that definition.

Comment: but I thought that the table is the same as relation.
was I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong.  If there is some piece of documentation that led you to believe this then, if you can quote it, someone can probably explain either that it is wrong or what it actually means rather than your incorrect understanding of it

Comment: thanks 
I edited the question with the explanation

Comment: Please do not post text information as screenshots

Comment: Ok, so a table is a "multiset" of tupples, which is like a "set" of tupples, but "multiset" allows dups and a "set" does not. Such techno mumbo jumbo can be confusing. Well, if a table has no PK or unique key, then you can insert 100% duplicate rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  sorry I will fix it 